# Case for multiple different versions of pi

Tags: pi-4, pi-3b+, cluster, case

Firstly, I'm not building a cluster, but due to lack of space, I just want to put my Pis into one case where they can share power and ethernet (POE)

I currently have a Pi 3B and 4B with plans on adding more as and when I find more uses!

I like the simplicity of the pi hut cluster case:

https://thepihut.com/products/cluster-case-for-raspberry-pi

But it doesn't look like it will fit the POE hat. Does buying larger spacers fix this issue? Did anyone use this case in the same way, or does anyone have any other recommendations?

Thanks

Russell

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: problem clarified